# <form:form method="POST" action="/<projectname>/escSave.html">

Tags: url-pattern

how action URL can be constructed dynamically. I have above URL in JSP and it is working fine in the local system.

```
http://localhost:8080/<projectname>/escSave.html
```

what needs to be added to work in all environment.

```
/server-dev.domain.com/<projectname>/escSave.html
```

Help me understand to fix.

Answer (score 0):

if escSave.html is in the root directory of the webpage it should be

```
<form:form method=“POST” action=“/escSave.html”>
```

relative to the current script:

```
<form:form method=“POST” action=“escSave.html”>
```

Comment: thanks alot for your quick reply Dimitri. I was performing some tests and understood culprit is not jsp, it is controller class.   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/addOps.html");